# nginx: redirect to named location inside if block

Tags: nginx

I have a location in nginx where GET and POST requests should go to different named locations. But this code doesn't work:

```
if ( $request_method = GET ) {
try_files /NON-EXISTENT @named_location_get
}

if ( $request_method = POST ) {
try_files /NON-EXISTENT @named_location_post
}
```

Because `try_files` is not allowed inside `if`.

Is there any other way to redirect request to named location, that would work inside `if`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know where this is documented, but I have seen configurations where a variable is used following the `@` symbol, to make the named `location` conditional.

Use this with a `map` block and you can eliminate the `if` blocks.

I have tested this example:

```
map $request_method $name {
    GET      named_location_get;
    POST     named_location_post;
    default  named_location_other;
}
server {
    ...
    location ... {
        try_files nonexistent @$name;
    }
    location @named_location_get {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a working solution, using variables for named locations works.

Unfortunately, the map directive works only on http config level, which makes it impossible to have different configurations for different locations and servers. For now I turned to using different fastcgi_pass inside if blocks, which is allowed in nginx. But the config still looks unbearably ugly.

Comment: "which makes it impossible to have different configurations for different locations and servers" . Why? Just use a different map output variable for each server you need. Even the servers are included in the http config (there is an include indeed) but they are defined for different server names so it is all fine.